# python: find all Latin Squares of a set (or partial square with fewer columns)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

EDIT:
Thanks to commenter Douglas Zare, I have renamed the title of this post with more appropriate terminology for anybody else who may be looking for something similar.  The code from David Eisenstat below was very helpful.

---

ORIGINAL POST:
I apologize for the lack of appropriate set theory terminology... but I'm a bit out of my depths here (though I suspect it's an easy problem).  I'm trying to develop an algorithm that will accept a set, and a number K, and return all possible "complete" partitions with K-sized subsets and with set coverage=K such that:

1. **any given subset will not have duplicates**
2. **combining the nth term across all subsets gives a complete partition of the set**
3. **the nth term of all subsets is unique across the rest of the subsets**

for example:

```
function({A, B, C, D}, 2)
```

should return all possible sets like this:

```
[AB, BC, CD, DA]
[AB, BD, CA, DC]
[AC, BD, CA, DB]
[AD, DA, CB, BC]
[BC, CA, DB, AD]
...
```

also, for what it's worth

4. **the order of the elements in an individual subset doesn't matter (as long as the other three rules are obeyed**

so the following are equivalent:

```
[AB, BA, CD, DC] = [BA, AB, DC, CD] = [AB, BA, DC, CD] = [BA, AB, CD, DC]
```

and

5. **order of the various subsets *does* matter:**

so the following are different:

```
[BC, CA, DB, AD] ≠ [CA, BC, AD, DB]
```

Put another way, in matrix terms: I'm looking for all matrices with `rows=len(set)` and `columns=K` such every column has exact cover and no item appears in any row more than once.

```
function({A, B, C, D}, 3)
```

would return all matrices like the following...

```
ABC      ADB    
BCD      DCA    
CDA      CBD    
DAB      BAC
```

I'm hoping for an answer in python, and using libraries like numpy is fine... but just a general algorithmic strategy would be appreciated as well. I thought something like [Algorithm X](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html) might come in handy... but I've been unable to make the leap from that to the problem outlined here...

Comment: "combining the nth term across all subsets gives a complete partition of the" and "the order of the elements in an individual subset doesn't matter (as long as the other three rules are obeyed)" contradict one another.  What does it mean to talk about the nth term of a subset if the order of the elements of a subset doesn't matter?

Comment: sorry... maybe I worded that strangely.  The order of the elements in any given subset only matter in relation to the other subsets. so `[AB, BA, CD, DC] = [BA, AB, DC, CD]` (because the nth element of each list has the same two items) but `[AB, BA, CD, DC] ≠ [DC, AB, BA, CD]` (even though the same four combos appear, just in a different order)... does that make sense?  Perhaps it's best explained by the matrix example at the end...

Comment: "Set," "set partition," and "partition" already have meanings. You should try to say what you mean without using those terms in unusual ways. You have a 2-dimensional array, or a matrix, which has some conditions on the rows and columns. I think what you have is some number of rows of a partial Latin square.

Comment: Thank you Douglas!  I know I'm not entirely using the appropriate terminology as I said.  The term **Latin square** is exactly what I was looking for...  If I can create all possible latin squares of a set, I think I could trim them down to partial latin squares according to my needs listed here.  (for what it's worth, I'll never have a set larger than say 8 items... usually less than 6)  I will start searching along those lines.  If anyone has an algorithm to suggest, feel free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doable with a backtracking search. Python 3:

```
import itertools
import operator


def valid(cols_so_far):
    for i, col1 in enumerate(cols_so_far):
        for col2 in cols_so_far[i + 1:]:
            if any(map(operator.eq, col1, col2)):
                return False
    return True


def enum(letters, k, cols_so_far=None):
    if cols_so_far is None:
        cols_so_far = (tuple(letters),)
    if not valid(cols_so_far):
        pass
    elif len(cols_so_far) == k:
        yield tuple(zip(*cols_so_far))  # transpose
    else:
        for perm in itertools.permutations(letters):
            yield from enum(letters, k, cols_so_far + (perm,))
```

Comment: Thank you David!  This is excellent.  I need some time to dig into this tonight, but I really appreciate the code as a starting point.